# Combine dataframes shifting rows. ValueError: Cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to append a new column to a dataframe with the values shifted down past the last value of the previous column.

Here's what I have so far:

```
column_names = ['Email']
query = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)
query['Email'] = all_emails['emails']
length_email = len(query['Email])
```

I am then looking to add a new column, but the values are shifted below the last value of the Email column.  The desired output is something like this.

```
Email                        Phone
blah@gmail.com
blahblah@gmail.com
blahblahblah@gmail.com
                             (123) 634-5030
                             (234) 134-1404
```

I have tried:

```
query['Phone Number'] = all_phone_numbers['phone_numbers'].shift(length email)
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says your data has duplicate index, and `pandas` does not know how to align these duplicates. For example, `all_phone_numbers` is something like:

```
          Phone
0    (123) 456-7890
0    (234) 123-6789
```

Now, when you do column assignment, which `value` should be chosen to put at index `0` of `query` dataframe?

That said, your desired operation is not column assignment, but rather `concat`, which stacks dataframes on top of each other:

```
query = pd.concat( (query, all_phone_numbers[['phone_numbers']] ))
```